# Is there a CASPOL.exe GUI command line generator?

Tags: .net, code-access-security, caspol

Is there a simple utility/GUI application for generating CASPOL commands?

Comment: This would work better on the site if you'd written it as a question, i.e. "how do you make using caspol.exe easier" then posted your find for the GUI as your answer (which you could eventually accept)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm posting this solution after I feel like I solved this mini-headache with .NET CAS.

After searching around for a CAS permissions solution this morning, I was trying to find a simple GUI utility that would allow me to generate Caspol.exe commands, and run them in Elevated mode on Vista / Win 7. Since I use this tool so infrequently I find myself having to re-learn it every time I need it.

So, after making one, figured I'd share it for other people who may find it useful. Simple little (free) WinForms app, source available at link below.

[Code Access Security Policy (CASPOL.exe) GUI Utility](http://brandonpotter.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/code-access-security-policy-caspol-exe-gui-utility/)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your nice and clean implementation how to find caspol.exe.